# Difference in behavior between ProcessInfo/Process.Start and the Run prompt

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pdf

I'm trying to open a PDF from within my application. I've gone through several iterations for this and have resolved that my only remaining option is to just open Adobe Reader passing the location of the PDF as an argument. The libraries I've looked at don't support what I need (rendering form fields) nor does the Telerik PDF control. So, I've absolutely explored the buy option over build.

Anyway, this works fine from the Run prompt like so:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\Temp\Bar.pdf"
```

However, from code, doing the following does NOT work:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe", location);
Process.Start(info);
```

Using Process.Start, I can see the Adobe process in my Task Manager list as a background process but there is no UI while it works flawlessly from Run where it shows up under App and gives the UI as I'd expect.

I don't see a way to force a UI to appear. The MainWindowHandle is 0, the WindowStyle is set to Normal, and CreateNoWindow is false.

Other things I've tried is setting the EnvironmentVariables collection manually and turning off shell execution. I've also tried loading the user profile into the process to no effect.

What do I need to do do here?

Comment: Your code works for me. Perhaps an issue with adobe reader, my version is 11.0.3 and i am using .Net 4.5. Or an ACL issue.

Comment: I don't know the solution to your problem but I know the tool I would use to try to figure it out. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx

Comment: Try running cmd.exe /c C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe...  That should make the environment look more line the command-line environment.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting around this situation entirely. I used iTextSharp to flatten the PDF and from there my normal tooling for rendering PDFs worked fine. Thankfully, this has other benefits for my needs as well.

I still couldn't solve the different in behavior I described. I was about to go down the path of Win32 via ShellExecute to leave a "where I left off" note.

Answer (score 0):

`*.Pdf` files are always opened using Adobe reader, unless you have installed some other pdf reader. So don't call the adobe application, just call the file using `Process.start(@"file location and name.pdf")`. Then the file will be opened in the default pdf reader.
You'll need a system reference `using System.Diagnostics;`

And here's another thing, above you have used `Process.Start()` to give the file location but remember this won't help if the application mentioned doesn't take any arguments/instructions.

> `Process.Start(@"application.exe", "instructions to application.exe")`

Comment: This was one of the first solutions I tried once I tried to use the PI object. It had no different behavior.